# MySQL how to select the nearest values to my variables

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have the following `query` where Im trying to retrieve matches, within a certain breathing space, of the variables entered.

```
SELECT fthg, ftag, avover, avunder, whh, wha, whd 
FROM full 
WHERE (whh < ($home_odds + 0.05) 
    AND whh > ($home_odds - 0.05) 
    AND wha < ($away_odds + 0.05) 
    AND wha > ($away_odds -0.05) 
    AND whd < ($draw_odds + 0.05) 
    AND whd > ($draw_odds - 0.05))
```

There are occasions where this returns 0 results so in that case I would like to retrieve the closest matching record to all three but Im not quite sure how to put the query together.

Basically this is the last resort if the other query doesn't return results, this one will return the next best thing no matter how far from the original values.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do the acronyms mean: fthg,ftag,avover (average over),avunder(average under),whh,wha,whd? Also where are they derived? Another table perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query would be simpler and more readable as this:

```
SELECT
    fthg,
    ftag,
    avover,
    avunder,
    whh,
    wha,
    whd
FROM full
WHERE ABS($home_odds - whh) < 0.05
    and ABS($away_odds - wha) < 0.05
    and ABS($draw_odds - whd) < 0.05
```

If that query returns nothing, you could run this one:

```
SELECT
    fthg,
    ftag,
    avover,
    avunder,
    whh,
    wha,
    whd
FROM full
ORDER BY
    ABS($home_odds - whh) + ABS($away_odds - wha) + ABS($draw_odds - whd)
LIMIT 1
```

It will return the row with the lowest deviation from the combination of those three pairs of fields.

Answer (score 1):

How about faking a distance calculation between the parameters you provide and the parameters you are comparing to? Something like

```
SELECT fthg, ftag, avover, avunder, whh, wha, whd 
FROM full 
ORDER BY 
        sqrt(abs(whh - $home_odds) * abs(whh - $home_odds)) +
        sqrt(abs(wha - $away_odds) * abs(wha - $away_odds)) +
        sqrt(abs(whd - $draw_odds) * abs(whd - $draw_odds))
```

This way, even if there are no matches given the range you are interested in, you can still get a closer result.

Comment: your solution might work but sqrt is very inefficient and useless in this case. See jfren484's answer.

Comment: @akostadinov I thought the challenge was using only one query here. Also this answer needs one more `+`.

Comment: @mabi, jfren484's answer is one query. If you can't understand how much inefficient your query is, I can't explain any better.

Comment: OK, loose the `SQRT`. It is inefficient. The query is provided to illustrate the concept.

Comment: @Ryan . . . The `abs()` is also unnecessary.  I would suggest:  `pow(whh - $home_odds, 2) + pow(wha - $away_odds, 2) + pow(whd - $draw_odds, 2)`.